# Python, calculator class definition

Tags: python, class, calculator, definition

I'm struggling with a practice problem below where I'm confused as to what the definitions would look like.

Create a class definition called 'calc' which is a calculator that supports these operators:  +, -, *, /
It should have the following methods:

```
def firstNumber(self, value):
def secondNumber(self, value):
def operator(self,op):
def answer(self):
def history(self):
```

Test Example:

```
c = calc()
c.firstNumber(4)
c.secondNumber(5)
c.operator('+')
print(c.answer())
#Should print 9 here.

c.firstNumber(5)
c.secondNumber(5)
c.operator('*')
print(c.answer())
#should print 25 here
print(c.history())
#should print:
#1.) 4 + 5 = 9
#2.) 5 * 5 = 25
```

Comment: Hi. Python documentation has [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) section on classes which should help guide you in creating classes and methods associated with the class.

Comment: Start with `class calc:`.  The rest of your sample code goes underneath that, and the implementations go underneath those.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Calculator(): #Create a class
    def calculate(): #Make function for calculate
        firstNumber = int(input("Enter your first number: ")) #Input first number and convert into interger
        secondNumber = int(input("Enter your second number: ")) #Input second number and convert into interger
        operator = input("Enter your operator: ") #Input operator
        if operator == "+": #Check if operator is +
            return firstNumber + secondNumber #Return result
        elif operator == "-": #Check if operator is -
            return firstNumber - secondNumber #Return result
        elif operator == "*": #Check if operator is *
            return firstNumber * secondNumber #Return result
        elif operator == "/": #Check if operator is /
            return firstNumber / secondNumber #Return result

Calc = Calculator() #Call the class
Result = Calc.calculate() #Calculate
print(Result) #Print the result into the console
```

So this is a basic calculator which will wait for our input for the firstNumber and then convert it to integer and also do the same thing with the secondNumber

Then it let us input the operator which is `+, -, *, /` and check if the input is one of an operator and then return the result

This is a very basic calculator, `lambda` or something I forget will make a calculator that same as the calculator you have seen, like when you input `1 + 6 - 3` it will return `4`

================================================================

Btw the history function I think it's hard for you cuz you need to do a database which very complex for beginner